# Firebase 3 Storage don't allow file updating/overwriting

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

Is there a method/ruleset for Firebase 3 storage to disable file updating or overwriting?

I found data.exists() for Database but no solution for Storage.

Answer (score 13):

TL;DR: In [Storage Security Rules](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security), `request.resource` ~= `newData.val()` and `resource` ~= `data.val()`, so you can use them similarly.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<bucket>/o {
    match /path/to/file {
      allow write: if resource == null; // if !data.exists() in DB land
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ocanal Can you provide info beyond "it's not working"

Comment: My storage is empty, I set the rule as you write, I always get 
{code: 403, message: "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"} error. my storage is still empty. if set allow write: true, I can upload.

Comment: Hrm, try `resource == null`, I'm not sure we implemented the unary `!` for "negation"

Comment: request.resource is new object getting written and resource is existing object.

Comment: I'm testing this in the emulator. When `path/to/file` contains a wildcard like `path/{filename}` then `resource == null` evaluates to `true` even when the file already exists. Seems like a non-trivial security vulnerability, no?

Comment: @CharlesHolbrow happens on mine too, I'm stuck now. Even using `allow update: if false` does not work, user can still update the file.

Comment: @RisalFajarAmiyardi Looks like `resource` always evaluates to `null` in the emulator, even when the resource exists. However in a live deployment, `resource` correctly evaluates to the existing resource (if it exists).