# Firesbase Storage security rules allow update rule not followed

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Firesbase Storage security rules allow update not working, can't prevent file over-write.

Example rule:

```
match /test/{userId}/{imageId} {
        allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow update: if false;
    }
```

Here I'm allowing authenticated users to only 'create' file, but not update/over-write.

**Expected behavior**: It shouldn't be allowed to update/over-write the existing file.

**Actual behavior**: When I'm again uploading a different file, but with same file name {over-writing the existing file}, then it's allowed to update/over-write.

How to prevent file update?

Comment: Nothing in the rule you've shared prevents overwriting an existing file. To do that, you'll want to check if there's an existing resource as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995011/firebase-3-storage-dont-allow-file-updating-overwriting

Comment: Oh wait, I now see that you've split `create` and `update`. Hmmm... I've never done it that way with Storage, only with Firestore. But it looks like that should work for Storage too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#granular_operations, so I'm not sure what's going wrong for you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, I have used granular operations, separating `create` and `update`. I've also check this with firestore, it works, but Storage doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the same structure as yours in Firebase Storage and turns out the rules are working for me.
[image]

I doubt if your structure is something like `/test/{userId}/images/{imageId}` which makes more sense if you are storing user generated content.
If the above if the case, then please update the rule to: `/test/{userId}/images/{imageId}`

If the issue still persists please share a screenshot of your Firebase Storage Directory structure.

Comment: In the simulator, you can do `update` operation. But in the android/web, you just use `put file`, means add files. So when I add to the same file location, that should be counted as update and it shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @hkchakladar just to be clear, do you say its adding anothwr file in the same ref? If the path to object is same then it should overwrite the object if allowed in the rules.

Comment: From your comment - " If the path to object is same then it should overwrite the object if allowed in the rules." It should overwrite the object IF ALLOWED in rules. My problem is I have disabled the overwrite, still it's getting overwritten.